# How to discard "Sync Changes" in Vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a "push" to be done for the "develop" branch but I don't want that to happen. And in my VsCode, in the Git part it's showing me "Sync Changes 1" but I don't want to push them.
I've already made a Pull Request on another branch with this same change. What do I do to make this message disappear?

[image]

Comment: Reset the develop branch back to before you made the change (**Warning!** This will delete your changes! Be sure you know what this means and that you want this to happen)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks! :}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of the "Sync Changes 1 ↑" button in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380600/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-sync-changes-1-%e2%86%91-button-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make develop be identical to master, the simplest way is just to recreate the pointer:

```bash
git branch -f develop master
```

Or, if you already have develop checked out:

```bash
git reset --hard master
```